# MEF and moonlight

Tags: mono, mef, moonlight

I am trying to figure out if MEF and moonlight work together. I heard Mono 2.8 got MEF already included. Although, will the full MEF work for moonlight applications?

For now I am using this adapted moonlight library http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/releases/view/35019.

Although, some functionality is stripped or this library is just to old.

I am searching for the DeploymentCatalog feature in moonlight.

[EDIT]

Can mono.addins be used in moonlight? Or will it be a problem to discover the export parts in the xap file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Deployment catalog is now avaible.

these are the steps I took:

-First I removed the assembly of the old adapted MEF library
-than I upgraded my moonlight to preview moonlight 3  http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/prerelease.aspx
-than changed the assembies  to the silverlight assemblies of MEF Preview 9

I than just worked (: